# How to pass source table name and target table name from text file in pentaho ETL

Tags: pentaho, transformation, kettle

I am begineer in Pentaho Data intregation..

In my transformation their is one table input (source) and one table output (target) and the data is copying from source to target.

What I want is that the table input step  fetches the tablename(source table which is in database) from some text file and loads the data to table output(target).the name of target table (whose structure is in database) is also to be fetch from text file...

If you need any details,which i missed to mention, please let me know.

Comment: What is the structure of the text file? Also, do these tables all have the same schema? If not, you may have to use `ETL Metadata Injection`.

Comment: Text file is simply a notepad file containing names of source tables line by lines...Yes for now the tables are in same schema...

Comment: What about the table schemas? Are they all the same?

Comment: Yes all the tables are in same schema

Comment: No, not the database schema. I mean do they all have the same structure, same DDL?

Comment: No,source tables have diferent structure..

Comment: Then as mentioned above, you can use the `ETL Metadata Injection` step. See the [Docs](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0L0/0Y0/0K0/ETL_Metadata_Injection) for examples. Also check the sample directory.